# How to access rapidJSON objects in order

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

Let's say I have a JSON object

```
{
   "Obj1":{
          "Obj2":{
               "Obj3":{


                }
          }
      }
  }
```

Is there a way to access each member without querying it's name or using an iterator.

If I have the reference to Obj1, how can I directly get the reference to the object Obj3. It seems as of now, I can only do that with an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Value& obj2 = document["Obj1"]
const Value& obj3 = obj2["Obj2"]
```

Comment: This is querying each object. What if we didn't know the names of the 2nd and 3rd object?

Comment: you asked a question about getting access to Obj3. Now you are changing the question? If you don't know the property name that you are trying to access, then JSON may not be the right format for you.

Comment: There is only 1 object. But the name changes from document to document. I can of course use an iterator to find the name of the first object. But I wanted an easier way

Comment: is it's position in the JSON fixed? in your example you could access obj1 as: const Value& obj1 = document[0], const Value& obj2 = obj1[0]...etc

Answer (score 0):

Using `MemberIterator` or `ConstMemberIterator` is the only way to iterate members of an object value, without knowing the keys a priori.